# use facebook session id from my android app to compare the session id generated in facebook php

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-android-sdk

Is it possible to use facebook session id from my android app to compare the session id generated in facebook php. I am using php-mysql framework.

In the sense,
I have an android app implementing facebook sdk and I get facebook session id when I login .
I want to use same session id everytime the user makes an http call hence securing the link and verifying that its the same facebook user.

If I am logging in from my android app with facebook sdk is there any way when I make http call and check the session id within my php page ?

Or is possible if he has logged in using facebook android sdk in my app it would bypass the login in php and check only session id with respect to the facebook unique id of that user.Or he has to login all over again??

Please help me out.I will greatly appreciate any help pertaining to this topic.Or any other suggestion for securing the http call made wrt the facebook user.

Thanks in Advance.